# Use setText to change the text to the variable title

Tags: java, android-studio

Super super new, but I am trying to do an android project and am on this step

-Use the setText method of the text view to change the text to the variable title

Can someone explain this to me? This is all I have currently. I've only had to use setText one other time and I already forgot it :/ Any tips where to find info on it would be helpful as well.

```
package app.mobiledev.navigationview;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SelectedFragment extends Fragment {
private String title;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    view.findViewById(R.id.title);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To set the text to something in the UI,
You need the object of this component.
For example if i have a text label ( No experience with android GUI, only Java FX but this should be the same) :

```
Label thisIsATextLabel;
thisIsATextLabel.setText(" THIS IS THE NEW TEXT OF THIS LABEL ");
```

Or

```
Label thisIsATextLabel;
String labelText = " this text is in a variable ";
thisIsATextLabel.setText(labelText);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout file, left window, under folder "app/res/layout"
maybe you have a text(TextView), like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

see the `android:id="@+id/title"` ?
you take that id `title` with `view.findViewById(R.id.title);` and
call `view.setText(title)` to set text to the screen.

The private String title, should have some kind of text/value to display it to the screen, like: `private String title = "My text title"` or call it like `title = "My text title"`.
Example:

```
package app.mobiledev.navigationview;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SelectedFragment extends Fragment {
private String title;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    title = "My text title";
    view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    view.setText(title);
}
```

You give any text you want to display on the screen in the `"My text title"` Like `title = "Some other text i like";`

Comment: Please, if something's wrong, or my answer is too long, please advice/correct me. Or if you have found a correct answer, please accept that answer as correct.